# .htaccess not routing as designed when rewriting dates

Tags: server, apache2, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess which is not performing as I think it should. I have a WP site which the owners decided to move the base path for the blog entries as /blog/, so all posts are 404ing now from search engines. While I have worked the redirects for the posts ok, the date categories like "/2015/03" also need redirecting. I've created a rule thus:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(200[1-9]|201[1-9])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/blog/$1
```

which works just fine on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

www.domain.com/2009/05 should go to: www.domain.com/blog/2009/05

But it's doing squat on the site. I have a dev version of the site to fiddle about with so can test and change without damaging the live site. Full mod_rewrite section:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(200[1-9]|201[1-9])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/blog/$1

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any clues? Server is Ubuntu with Apache2.

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess` files  `^` matches the start of this sub-directory, so you
should not use `^/` in patterns.

Also, your pattern `201[1-9]` is not matching 2010.

Comment: Thanks for responding @meuh. I understand that different mod_rewrite modules are different in respect of the `^/` slash but either way it doesn't work. Thanks for pointing out the `[0-9]` - corrected!

Comment: ok. Are you sure you have the mod_rewrite module? Try putting a syntax error in the section. Do you have `Options FollowSymLinks`? Do you need a [RL] flags at the end of the rule which has a full url?

Comment: Hi, yes, rewrites are working fine on the rest of the site so the module is there and working. Adding an error does produce a server 500 so that section is being read. Adding [RL] at the end of the rule caused a 500 too. `Options FollowSymLinks` is present. 

Baffling.

Comment: When all else fails... you could add `LogLevel debug` inside the `IfModule` block.

Comment: Hi, I might just have to do that. I'm now getting weird redirects with /blog/blog/... stacking up on the url - even with a clean .htaccess file - only the WP redirect present. I'm beginning to suspect the apache config so I'll look wider than just the htaccess. Many thanks for your responses!